# How can I check whether a word is in a dictionary or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm loading strings from a preloaded core data database which happen to be all CAPITAL.

I want to check if each word is in the English dictionary, and if so try to lowercase it like a regular sentence, if not keep it upper case (for abbreviations and such).

Is there a way to do this with iOS 4?

Comment: I've tried looking for dictionary built into the SDK, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementation for Noah's answer:

```
-(BOOL) isDictionaryWord:(NSString*) word 
{
    UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [word length]);
    NSRange misspelledRange = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:word range: searchRange startingAt:0 wrap:NO language: currentLanguage ];
    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound;
}

NSString string = @"lalala";
if ([self isDictionaryWord:string]) string = [string lowercaseString];
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 3.2, you can use the UITextChecker class to access the system dictionary. Use its `-rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:range:startingAt:wrap:language:` method: if it returns a range whose `location` is `NSNotFound`, all of the words in the string you provided are in the dictionary or have already been “learned” by the text checker.